# Using Springboot on Mac, command "spring" not found

Tags: macos, spring-boot, homebrew

Using Homebrew to install springboot onto my personal mac, I have been running into errors, following tutorials I used:

```
brew install springboot
```

With the following error:

```
==> We've Moved!
Warning: Spring Boot has relocated to spring-io/tap
```

so i did ...

```
brew tap spring-io/tap
```

It installed but I am trying to check the confirm the version using

```
spring --version
```

Through a bit of research I still cant find an alternative command but the change is quite recent so I'm hoping someone else has come across this issue.

[Spring Boot tweet Jan 15 2021 with following statement](https://twitter.com/springboot/status/1349954944451821572?s=20)

Mac users: Please note that we've relocated the Spring Boot CLI to a new Homebrew tap. Upgrade with:

```
brew tap spring-io/tap
brew uninstall springboot
brew install spring-boot
```

Can someone confirm if I followed this incorrectly or there is a different command to use for spring version, thank you.

Comment: If you type, `brew list` you should get spring-io/tap/springboot or something similar in there. Do you?

Comment: I think your installation may have failed. I followed the instructions you quoted from their tweet and `spring --version` works for me:

Comment: @xrisk i have spring-boot under formulae

Comment: so do I. what do you get if you just enter the command `spring`? You should get a usage statement. Try opening another terminal if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong install, need

```
brew install spring-boot
```

to be able to run the spring command